# Subprocess started from Python runs slower than from bash

Tags: python, bash, benchmarking

I am using the following Python code to run a subprocess and collect its output as a string:

```
def run(command):
    ''' Run a command and return the output as a string '''
    args = shlex.split(command)
    out = subprocess.Popen(args,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    # Save to log file
    with open("log_file.txt", "a") as log_file:
        log_file.write("$ " + command + "\n")
        log_file.write(out)

    return out
```

My goal is to run a benchmark application (`openssl speed`) multiple time and use Python to parse the output and calculate the average results.

However, I have noticed that the results are consistently slower (about 10%) than when I run the same command directly from the command line in bash.

How would you explain this?

**EDIT**

The output of the command is quite short: about 10 lines.
Also, note that the benchmark does not print any output while the performance test is running. It only prints the results outside the *critical loop*.

In the script I only run the benchmark of a particular cipher at a time, so for example I use the following arguments:

```
openssl speed -elapsed -engine my_engine rsa2048
```

Note that I am using a custom engine (target of the benchmark) and not the standard software implementation.
My engine spawns another pthread but I would not expect to make a big difference since the Python script is not supposed to interact in any way.

Comment: How much output does it produce? The Python-spawned instance may block more if you aren't reading from its output pipe fast enough.

Comment: The subcommand may detect if it's running in what looks like tty/terminal or not and change its behaviour (and thus running time) based on that.

Comment: Running `openssl speed` locally prompts me for user input. You don't seem to be setting anything for your subcommands' stdin. Are you running `openssl speed` with any extra arguments or otherwsie handling the expected user input?

Comment: @chepner, I have edited the description to answer your question

Comment: @TomDalton have edited the description to answer your questions

Comment: Having the same issue with a database (MonetDB). Have you ever found the problem @Muffo?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember finding a solution for this.